# Regex non-greedy pattern match

Tags: regex

I need to match the line before a particular string. I am using `^.+(?<=abc)` regex to match, this works for greedy pattern. i am looking for non-greedy pattern.

e.g `/123/345/abc/v2/xyz/abc/dgdes/aegweg`

expected result: `/123/345/abc`

What i get is `/123/345/abc/v2/xyz/abc/`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Try `^.+?(?<=abc)`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Actually, *use* [`^.+?(?<=abc)`](https://regex101.com/r/7uCZza/1)

Comment: @Wiktor - That's what I wrote:)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You said *try*, while it is the correct regex for the current scenario. No need trying, this should be used.

Comment: @Wiktor - Oh, now that you've mentioned, I see the emphasis on "use" :). Cheers

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks its working now.